# What is the point of (Compactness Theorem in the) Overspill Principle?

Tags: logic, model-theory, infinity, first-order-logic

I am trying to understand the basics of computation theory. The [Overspill Principle](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MA_Algebra/MAml_Mathematical%20logic/Boolos%20G.,%20Burgess%20J.P.,%20Jeffrey%20R.C.%20Computability%20and%20logic%20%284ed.,%20CUP,%202002%29%28ISBN%200521007585%29%28370s%29_MAml_.pdf) ([also at google](http://books.google.ee/books?id=0LpsXQV2kXAC&lpg=PA353&vq=overspill&pg=PA147#v=onepage&q=overspill%20principle&f=true)) basically says <strike>if you are cool you can do everything</strike>

> Let Г be a sentence of predicate logic such that for any natural
>   number m ≥ 1, there is a model of Г with at least n elements. Then Г has
>   a model with infinitely many elements.

A model is basically a set. The theorem says that if you have a model larger than any model of finite size, you have a model of infinite size. But that is obvious. It is obvious that if, no matter how larger is your finite model, I can always come up with a larger one, this means that my set contains an infinite model. Even the proof of the principle involves expanding Г with $I_1, I_2, \ldots, I_m$ (where $I_m$ says that model size is larger than $m$), applying Complactness theorem to it (which says that such model, larger than $m$, exists) and finally, my common sense is used: the author says that the model must be infinite because it is larger than any finite m. But is clear from the very beginning. What is the point of introducing all these $I_m$s and applying the compactness?

Comment: Note that antecedent of the compactness theorem is not that $\exists\mathcal{M}\forall n(|\mathcal{M}|\geq n)$, in which case it would be a bit of a triviality. It's "$\forall n\exists\mathcal{M}(|\mathcal{M}|\geq n)$", which only says that you have an endless supply of finite models. It's a pretty substantial result that having enough sizes of finite models means there's an infinite model out there, too.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Can we reaplace $|M|$ with $m$? $\exists m\forall n(m \ge n)$ is not the same as  $\forall n\exists m(m \ge n)$. Whereas the first says that there exists a row whose every cell complies to a property (it has 1 in every column), the second is not that strict. It tells just for every column, you'll find a cell (i.e. there is a row), containing 1. First says that the largest is one and the same machine. The other says that we can find a machine larger than every your number n2 but it is not necessary the same machine that is larger than another size n1. How does it break my logic?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I guess that there is a lot of machines larger than 0. There is ten less machines larger than 10. We have a lower triangular matrix, the amount of ones per column is decrementing as we make one step to the right, to the infinity. I guess that in the end of this process, we end up with single row of all ones -- the infinite machine that is larger than any (finite) number. Since, by definition, such model exists, it must be that model satisfies both $\exists M \forall n (|M| \ge n)$ and $\forall n \exists M (|M| \ge n)$. When you satisfy the stronger req, you satisfy the midler.

Comment: Your logic is broken in the case you believe the former, stronger formula is the antecedent of the compactness theorem, which it is not. If you do not believe this, then your logic is still broken for very different reasons :p

Comment: There are not actually any fewer machines greater than 10 than there are greater than 0 if there's an infinite number of them; that might be one problem. It's not generally true that having a lot of different finite sizes of something implies an infinite something; there are arbitrarily large
 finite proper initial segments of $\mathbb{N}$, but it obviously doesn't follow that there are any infinite ones.

Answer (score 4):

To see how this is not obvious, let us see an example out of the grasp of first-order logic.

Consider $\cal L$ the logic obtained by adding $\forall^\infty$ quantifier, whose interpretation is "all but finitely many". This logic is **stronger** than first-order logic, it can express **more** things.

In first-order logic we can say something like "The universe has exactly/at most $42$ elements" in order to say that it is finite. The overspill principle says that in a first-order theory, if it cannot prove that some natural number $n$ is an upper bound to the size of models, then there is an infinite model.

But consider a theory in the logic $\cal L$ whose only axiom is this: $$\forall x\forall^\infty y(x=y)$$

This axiom says that every $x$ is equal to all but finitely many elements, that is to say that if $M$ is a model of this axiom, then for every $x\in M$ the set $M\setminus\{x\}$ is finite. Therefore if $M$ satisfies this axiom, it has to be finite since it is the union of $M\setminus\{x\}$ and $\{x\}$ which are two finite sets.

But not only this. Given any finite non-empty set, $M$, then $M$ is a model for this axiom. Because every $x$ is only different from finitely many elements of the universe -- $M$.

So the axiom above has a model of size $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ but no infinite model.

So what goes wrong here? The fact that $\cal L$ does not have a compactness theorem. In first-order logic, however, the overspill principle shows that unless you can specify how large is the universe, there is an infinite model.

Comment: I do not understand what `initial segment is finite` means. You say like the models are finite but cannot be so in that language/theory. This just means that there are no models. Might be the problem is that I do not understand what the `finite linear order` is.

Comment: Do you understand what a finite set is? Do you understand what a linear order is? This is a logic **stronger** than first-order logic. It can express **more** things than what first-order logic can. In particular it can express the statement "The universe is finite" without explicitly expressing how many elements are in the universe. I think that if you don't understand the statement "finite linear order" then you need to go back to the basics, much much before the compactness theorem. In any case, I'll edit with a simpler example.

Comment: You say that M is finite because it is infinite otherwise. I see no problem with M infinite. Actually I see that axiom says that our $x$-es are equal to any $y$ from infinity rather than differ from it. Might be you wanted to say that one element cannot equal to everything (including other, distinct elements) or just missed a negation?

Comment: If $M$ is infinite, pick *any* $x$, then the set $M\setminus\{x\}$ is infinite. So the axiom is not true there.

Comment: Ok, it seems that I have got the meaning of the theorem. It says that if your model is infinite, you get a contradiction - all elements are equal, which is nonsense. So, the model is finite. However, if you say that your models can be finite yet there is always exists a larger one, you say that the proof based on Compactness is wrong. Overspill proof says that existence of everlarger models means that infinite one exists.

Comment: @Val, the proof is not wrong. The proof is for first-order logic. Here we extended the logic by adding a new type of quantifier. This is not first-order logic anymore. But I had to do something like that if I wanted to give you an example for a theory which has models of arbitrarily large finite sizes, but no infinite model. And the point is that this stronger logic lacks a compactness theorem.

Comment: Ok, let it give up the compactness. I am attracting attention to the point in the proof which says that model must be infinite. Do you see that in the overspill proof? It says that if we can always find a model larger than any k then we have an infinite model. How does availability of compactness affect this implication?

Comment: @Val: If we have compactness, then we can add to the theory the statements "There are at least $k$ elements in the universe", which are expressible in first-order logic. Then by showing that every finite subset of the theory has a model, compactness assures that the entire theory has a model. But in this model there are at least $k$ elements for every finite $k$, and therefore there must be infinitely many elements in the universe of that model, so the model is infinite. And if it satisfies the original theory with more axioms, it certainly satisfies the original theory we cared about.